AWS Disaster Recovery Testing Across Zones | Site-to-Site VPN | TCP Connection Issue | How single client to multiple server IPs
I've deployed services on AWS EC2 that act as a server and have established a TCP connection on IP xx.xx.xx.30. The client is currently transferring data through this IP, and everything is functioning as expected.
Now, the client has requested to test disaster recovery (DR) in a different availability zone but within the same region. Our DevOps team has copied the services from xx.xx.xx.30 and deployed them to xx.xx.xx.31, establishing services in two separate zones on AWS EC2.
The goal is that when the connection on xx.xx.xx.30 goes down, the client’s data communication should seamlessly switch to xx.xx.xx.31. How can we implement this DR testing so that the IP change occurs instantly without data loss during the failover?
What would be the best approach?
